# Ошибка в Django при redirect

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте, в Django во views.py в функции прописываю:

```
return redirect('/')
```

(в начале прописал: from django.shortcuts import redirect)

Но при переходу на страницу с этой функцией выдаёт ошибку:

```
'str' object has no attribute 'regex'
```

Что делать?

Comment: дайте, пожалуйста, всю функцию и весь стек. Сам по себе redirect умеет так делать, наверное, ошибка где-то еще. Какая версия джанго?

Comment: Проверь urls.py или выложи сюда. Возможно, ошибка там.